# xcode 8.2 IPA validation warning

Tags: ios, xcode8.2

[image]

after formatting my Mac issue with  Xcode certificate 
download all certificates from developer.apple 
but till warning
how can I solve this ?

Comment: Hey OP, please consider marking my answer as 'accepted' if it helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to press `Reset`. Then wait for an email Apple sends you about revoking your certificates and then click `Try Again` in Xcode.

If that does not help, go to Xcode's settings, and under the account tab, click on your account and open the certificates and click `download all`.

If the problem still persists, go to Apple's Developer Member Center and manually download and install (double-click) the certificates.

That should resolve your issues.